# How to sum and count together using Codeigniter Datamapper?

Tags: sql, codeigniter, count, sum, codeigniter-datamapper

I want to do something like this with Codeigniter Wanwizard Datamapper.

```
SELECT COUNT(amount), SUM(amount) FROM mytable
```

Basically I want to extract both the total amount and how many row included in a single query.
But I couldn't find a way in the documentation page here http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/ because there's select_sum() for SUM function but no select_count() for COUNT.
Is there any way to do it just like in my case?
Thank you.

Comment: just found it myself...here's the answer :)
    $object->select_func('COUNT', '*', 'count')
    $object->select_sum('amount')->get()

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select("COUNT(ratting) as v_count, SUM(ratting) as v_sum");
$this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
$row = $this->db->get('user')->row();
```

Output

```
stdClass Object
(
    [v_count] => 3
    [v_sum] => 7.5
)
```

Hope will help you.

Answer (score 0):

To transform this

```
SELECT COUNT(amount), SUM(amount) FROM mytable
```

in a query in controller with Codeigniter and Datamapper, you can use

```
$p = new mytablemodel();
$p->select_sum('amount','total')->select_func('COUNT', 'amount', 'count')->get();
```

and to show, you use

```
echo $p->total;
echo $p->count;
```

you can add conditionals too:

```
$p = new mytablemodel();
$p->select_sum('amount','total')->select_func('COUNT', 'amount', 'count')->where('status', 1)->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$p = new Film();
$p->select('COUNT(amount), SUM(amount)')->get();
```